# PhpSpreadsheet #ЗНАЧ! в формуле =SUMPRODUCT(E8:E15,F8:F15)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Добрый день!

В ячейках **E8:E15** и **F8:F15** записаны числа. При записи формулы **=SUMPRODUCT(E8:E15,F8:F15)** в ячейку **C4** с помощью **PhpSpreadsheet**, в Microsoft Excel 2010 появляется ошибка **#ЗНАЧ!**. Если нажать в выпадающем меню на пункт "Изменить в строке формул" и просто нажать Enter, то ошибка исчезает, и на ее месте появляется верное значение. В LibreOffice и OpenOffice все работает нормально.

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("tmpl.xls");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

for($i = 8; $i < 16; $i++) {
    $worksheet->getCell('F'.$i)->setValue(1);
    $worksheet->getCell('E'.$i)->setValue(2);
}

$worksheet->getCell("C4")->setValue('=SUMPRODUCT(E8:E15,F8:F15)');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Также все верно работает, если записываю в формат xlsx или записываю в формулу не диапазоны, а отдельные ячейки.

Может кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить?

**UPD.**

Попробовал добавить значение

```
$val = $worksheet->getCell("C4")->getCalculatedValue();
$worksheet->getCell("C4")->setCalculatedValue($val);
$worksheet->getCell("D4")->setValue($val);
```

В соседней ячейке D4 записывается верное значение, а в C4 все равно выводится ошибка.

Comment: Возможно, кроме формулы надо писать значение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Попробовал добавить значение с помощью setCalculatedValue, не помогло.

Comment: забавно,  никогда не задумывался, что в нерусской локали аргументы в формулах экселя запятой разделяются, а не точкой с запятой :) _(или вернее сказать - системным разделителем элементов списка)_